How to get vector field from Poisson brackets?
Steinacker defines the Hamilton vector field as any field s.t.:
$$\{f,g\}=V_f[g].$$
I really can't understand this. The Poisson algebra is closed with respect to Poisson brackets (i.e. $\{\cdot ,\cdot\}:A\times A\rightarrow A$), so I expect that the Poisson bracket of two functions is again a function. How is it possible that we have a vector field? Steinacker then gives proof of this going to local coordinates, but in this way, he demonstrates that $(V_f)^a=\{f,x^a\}$. Well, now that it is an equation for the components for me it's okay, but the field? I would probably understand if what we were saying was that the function obtained through the Poisson bracket operation generates a vector field that is related to the Lie bracket of the Vector fields of f and g, but it's not what is written in that formula.

A vector field is a linear map which each smooth functions and spits out smooth functions. In this case, $V_f$ is a vector field, $g$ is a smooth function, and so $V_f[g]$ is also a smooth function.
Given a function $f\in \mathcal A$ (where $\mathcal A$ is the Poisson algebra of smooth functions equipped with the Poisson bracket), we are defining the vector field $V_f$ such that $V_f[g] := \{f,g\} \in \mathcal A$. It is a simple exercise to demonstrate that this satisfies the requirements of a vector field.

Just to expand @J.Murray's answer:  that $V[g] = V^\mu \partial_\mu g$.
